# Supertype and subtype exception handling

Tags: java, exception

Consider this code:

```
public class CheckException 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {       
       int a = 10;
        try{
            int c = a/0;
        } catch(Exception e){

        } catch(ArithmeticException e1){    \\ compilation error

        }
    }   
}
```

My doubt is compilation error is generated at the second catch because it's already handled by the super type Exception. But why compilation error does not come when the second catch block comes to the first's position and and first comes to the second's position(Like below)?

```
public class CheckException {

public static void main(String [] args){

    int a = 10;
    try{
        int c = a/0;
    } catch(ArithmeticException e){
//       System.out.println("1");   
    } 
    catch(Exception e1){
//          System.out.println("2");
    }
}

}
```

Then also the first block(i.e. ArithmeticException) will handle the exception before it reaches to catch(Exception e).

**Modified**

Now I am adding all the unchecked exceptions before catch(Exception e).

```
public class CheckException {

public static void main(String [] args){

    int a = 10;
    try{
        int c = a/0;
    } catch(ArithmeticException e){
     System.out.println("1");   
    } 
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(ClassCastException  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(AssertionError e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(ExceptionInInitializerError  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(StackOverflowError  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(NoClassDefFoundError  e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(ArrayStoreException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(NegativeArraySizeException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(SecurityException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(UnsupportedOperationException e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
    catch(Exception e1){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}

}
```

Now, all the unchecked exceptions are getting handled before reaching catch(Exception e). So, is there anymore unchecked exception other than these because of which compilation error is not generated? or is it something else?

Comment: Because there are unchecked `Exception`s other than the `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: You no need to have second catch block for the logic inside try block. Control goes to the second catch block(Exception) only when it throws other than ArithmeticException. Hence you can still write second catch block and this cause no issue at all.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what if I add all the unchecked exceptions before the last block? Will it be the same?

Comment: I added some code. Please look above.

Comment: It won't because you can't know which unchecked exceptions may be thrown at runtime. The compile-time and runtime classpaths are not at all the same and exception classes may also be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, the catch blocks are triggered in the order in which they appear in the source file.

Thus, if the more general `Exception` comes first, it will trigger also if a an `ArithmeticException` is thrown, and the second catch block is unreachable.

On the other hand, if the catch block for the more specific `ArithmeticException` comes first, then the catch block for the `Exception` does not become unreachable, because there are subclasses of `Exception` that are not caught by the first block.

Answer (score 1):

The more specific exception - `ArithmeticException`  - should come first, since it allows you to handle it differently then the general handling of `Exception`.

If you put the exception handler or `Exception` first, you make the handler of `ArithmeticException` dead code, since it can never be reached - any `ArithmeticException` will be caught by the handler of `Exception`.